# What is Belle's secret?

Tags: margery-allingham, death-of-a-ghost

The final pages of *Death of a Ghost* describe Mrs. Lefcadio looking at a self-portrait of her husband, and much is made of how different it is from the famous Sargent portrait of the man. And then she turns it over:

> Written across the back in the painter’s enormous hand was a single phrase:
>   *'Your secret, Belle darling.'*
>   The old lady returned to the portrait. She touched her lips with her forefinger and pressed it on the painted mouth.
>   'Oh, Johnnie,' she said sadly. 'Such a lot of trouble, my dear. Such a lot of trouble.'

What is the secret John Lefcadio was reminding Belle of, and which of the novel's troubles did it cause or represent?

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the full quote describing Lafcadio's self-portrait here:

> It showed the same face which smiled so proudly from Sargent, but there was a great difference.
>
> John Lafcadio's famous beard was here only suggested, and the line of his chin, a little receding, was viciously drawn in. The lips were smiling, their sensuous fullness overmphasized. The flowing locks were shown a little thin and the high cheekbones caricatured.
>
> The eyes were laughing, or at least one of them laughed. The other was completely hidden in a grotesque wink.
>
> It was cruel and revealing, the face of a man who was, if half genius, also half buffoon.
>
> Belle Turned it over. Written across the back in the painter's enormous hand was a single phrase:
>
> *Your secret, Belle darling.*

So John Lafcadio has painted a very unflattering self-portrait which pictures him as a buffoon. In fact, he and Belle both knew that he **was** in fact, partly a buffoon, and this is the secret. This aspect of his personality is what led indirectly to most of the novel's troubles — although I won't go into detail here to keep this answer relatively spoiler-free.